# Why there exists 2 different results as I just change one seemingly unimportant boolean variable?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, debugging, vector

I came across a problem today. I was asked to find the smallest number by concatenating a set of numbers ranging from 0 to 100( both excluded). For example, I input an array containing `{5, 42, 56, 8, 28, 34, 49, 3}`. I should output `2833442495568` by concatenating `28, 3, 34, 42, 49, 5, 56, 8`. So I write the following code.

```cpp
//  Nums.hpp

#ifndef Nums_hpp
#define Nums_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class Nums {
private:
    int _num;
    vector<int> digit;
public:
    Nums(int num);
    int get_num();
    int get_i_digit(int i);
    int get_digit_num();
    void print();
};

#endif /* Nums_hpp */


//  Nums.cpp

#include "Nums.hpp"

Nums::Nums(int num)
{
    _num = num;
    vector<int> temp = vector<int>();
    while (num != 0) {
        temp.push_back(num % 10);
        num = num / 10;
    }
    for (int i = int(temp.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        digit.push_back(temp[i]);
    }
}

int Nums::get_num()
{
    return _num;
}

int Nums::get_i_digit(int i)
{
    return digit[i];
}

int Nums::get_digit_num()
{
    return int(digit.size());
}

void Nums::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < int(digit.size()); i++) {
        std::cout << digit[i];
    }
}


//  main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

#include "Nums.hpp"

using std::vector;
using std::cout;

const int N = 8;
const int MAXVALUE = 100;
const int MINVALUE = 0;

bool compare(Nums a, Nums b);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    srand(1);
    vector<int> nums = vector<int>(N);
    vector<Nums> digit_nums = vector<Nums>();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        nums[i] = rand()%(MAXVALUE - MINVALUE) + MINVALUE;
        cout << nums[i] << ' ';
        digit_nums.push_back(Nums(nums[i]));
    }
    cout << '\n';
    
    sort(digit_nums.begin(), digit_nums.end(), compare);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        digit_nums[i].print();
    }
    cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}

bool compare(Nums a, Nums b)
{
    bool judge;
    if (a.get_num() == b.get_num()) {
        judge = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (a.get_i_digit(0) < b.get_i_digit(0)) {
            judge = true;
        }
        else if (a.get_i_digit(0) > b.get_i_digit(0))
        {
            judge = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (a.get_digit_num() == 2 && b.get_digit_num() == 2) {
                if (a.get_i_digit(1) < b.get_i_digit(1)) {
                    judge = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    judge = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (a.get_digit_num() == 1) {
                    if (b.get_i_digit(1) < b.get_i_digit(0)) {
                        judge = false;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        judge = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (b.get_digit_num() == 1) {
                    if (a.get_i_digit(1) < a.get_i_digit(0)) {
                        judge = true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        judge = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                    judge = false;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << a.get_num() << ':' << b.get_num() << ' ' << judge << '\n'; // This can help me debug
    return judge;
}
```

The result is right now. The result is shown here.

```
7 49 73 58 30 72 44 78 
30:7 1
78:30 0
78:7 0
30:7 1
49:7 1
73:7 1
58:7 1
7:7 0
44:7 1
72:7 1
7:7 0
72:7 1
49:30 0
73:49 0
58:73 1
58:49 0
44:73 1
44:58 1
44:49 1
44:30 0
72:73 1
72:58 0
304449587273778
```

But when I change a seemingly unimportant part in the `compare` function:

```cpp
bool compare(Nums a, Nums b)
{
    bool judge;
    if (a.get_num() == b.get_num()) {
        judge = true;
    }
    // the other codes are not changed
}
```

The result turns wrong.

```
7 49 73 58 30 72 44 78 
30:7 1
78:30 0
78:7 0
30:7 1
49:7 1
73:7 1
58:7 1
7:7 1
72:7 1
44:7 1
78:7 0
44:7 1
7:78 1
58:30 0
44:58 1
44:30 0
30:44 1
49:44 0
72:44 0
78:44 0
44:44 1
73:49 0
73:49 0
44:49 1
49:73 1
44:30 0
78:73 0
72:78 1
72:73 1
58:78 1
58:73 1
58:72 1
304449587273787
```

I cannot find out the reason! Could you help me?

Comment: compare needs to define the behaviour of `<`, not `==`.

Comment: `a < a` should return false, else you break strict weak ordering needed by `std::sort` and have UB.

Comment: comparison seems over complicated (`return std::to_string(lhs) + std::to_string(rhs) < std::to_string(rhs) + std::to_string(lhs);` should do the job).